# Disable corner resize but keep both horizontal/vertical resize in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I've been tinkering around with JQuery's [resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) property and as of late, I've not found there to be a suitable type for what I'm trying to achieve.

The following example shows that you can resize both vertically and horizontally which is what I want, but you can also drag the corner box to resize which is not what I want. Is there a way to remove this box to make it resizable only by dragging the edges of the container?

```js
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out their docs here: https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

is this what you want to achieve?

```js
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({ handles: "n, e, s, w" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```